# HTTP basic authentication for JAX-RS without web.xml

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, basic-authentication, jboss-eap-7

I'm implementing a REST service within an EJB-JAR within an EAR running on the JBoss EAP 7.1.

The unsecured version of the service works fine, but adding even basic HTTP-authentication turned out to be a challenge, since within an EJB-JAR I found no way to specify any required web.xml-entries, like `<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>`

So my question is:

#### How can I configure JAX-RS to use HTTP authentication within an EJB-JAR?

Additional information:

- To make things simpler I use default ManagementRealm like this

  ```
  <security-domain name="my-security-domain" cache-type="default">
      <authentication>
          <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
              <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
          </login-module>
          <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
              <module-option name="realm" value="ManagementRealm"/>
          </login-module>
      </authentication>
  </security-domain>
  ```
- In EJB-jar:

  ```
  @Stateless
  @Path("/my-rest")
  @SecurityDomain(value = "my-security-domain")
  @DenyAll
  public class MyRestStatelessBean {
          @PUT
          @RolesAllowed("admin")
          @Path("/doAdminStuff")
          public void doAdminStuff() {
              // Implementation
          }
  }
  ```

Comment: An EAR file can contain one or more WAR files and the WAR file should be able to have a `web.xml` which can specify it's security requirements.  How are you packaging things up?

Comment: I package my ejb jar within the ear file and I would like to avoid moving my REST beans from ejb-jar to WAR. That is what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use the **Proactive authentication** feature of the Undertow, that is actually ON by default. Specifying HTTP-BASIC-Authentication header within the request, makes Undertow to try to login the user even through my REST service due to missing `web.xml` doesn't require any type of authentication.

My complete configuration (using **Management** JBoss users from `mgmt-users.properties`):

```
# Define my security domain
/subsystem=security/security-domain=MY-SECURITY-DOMAIN:add(cache-type=default)

# Link Untertow to Elytron for authentication
/subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=MY-SECURITY-DOMAIN:add(   \
           http-authentication-factory="management-http-authentication"   \
)

# Add BASIC-HTTP-Authentication support to Elytron
/subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=management-http-authentication:list-add( \
           name=mechanism-configurations,                                               \
           value={mechanism-name="BASIC",                                               \
               mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name="ManagementRealm"}]          \
           }                                                                            \
)

# Not sure, why is this required...
/subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=MY-SECURITY-DOMAIN:add(  \
           security-domain="ManagementDomain")
```